# Capture XML inline comment Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried using `(?<=[^\n])<!--([^\n]*)` currently it's not capturing inline `<!-- comment --> <element />` and for some reason also capture newline comment only. My current approach was to use lookbehind newline (`\n`) and if it's an inline comment erase it with empty space.

Test string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<element /> <!-- comment -->

<element />
<!-- comment -->
<element />
<!-- comment --> <element />

<element>
  <!-- Comment -->
  <element>
  </element>

  <!-- another comment -->
</element>
```

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there any better way?

<sub>**PS:** Have tried using parser and haven't found any parser that differentiate between inline and newline comment.</sub>

Comment: Why you care if comment is on same line or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.*?` to match anything inside a comment and 2 possible version of inline comments combined:

```js
console.log(str.match(/(?<!\n\s*)<!--.*?-->|<!--.*?-->(?!\s*\n)/g));
```

```html
<script>
const str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<element /> <!-- inline comment 1 -->

<element />
<!-- comment -->
<element />
<!-- inline comment 2 --> <!-- inline comment 3 --> <element /> 

<element>
  <!-- Comment -->
  <element>
  </element>

  <!-- another comment -->

</element>`
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to capture every comment. Is it possible to take only inline comment? From your snippet it would be comment 1 and 3.

Comment: Спасибо! it capture every inline perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice: `(?:^[^\S\r\n]*<!--(.*?)-->[^\S\r\n]*<|>[^\S\r\n]*<!--(.*?)-->[^\S\r\n]*$)`

`[^\S\r\n]` is any `\s` that isn't a newline character

The branch before `|` covers inline comments before a tag (NB: that includes another comment!).

The branch after `|` covers inline comments after a tag (NB: that includes another comment!).

The content of each match is contained either `match[1]` or `match[2]`.

If you want every single line comment, that would be a stripped down version: `(?:[^\S\r\n]*<!--(.*?)-->[^\S\r\n]*)`

Comment: Doesn't seems to work on https://regex101.com. Can you please make a snippet as to how it works?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qrINLH/1

Comment: Also for the stripped down version: https://regex101.com/r/nvhojf/1